# Requiring React components in my html files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I've set up a node.js server with express and I'm rendering an html page with jsx code inside. Everything is working fine except that I don't know how to import other jsx components in my html file to use them in my main script.

I've tried something like

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./Modulo.jsx" />
```

But I get an error `GET http://localhost:5000/Modulo.jsx`

[image: error]

Here's the content of my Modulo.jsx

```
var Modulo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
  }
});
```

And this is my main module `index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var React = require('react');
var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var swig = require('swig');
var path = require('path');

app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

server.listen(5000);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('ModuleScreen');
});
```

ModuleScreen is a simple html file where I try to import my Modulo.jsx

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: Have you made sure the path is right?

Comment: I have no more info on the error (updated with a screen). And yes I'm sure that the path is the correct one.

Comment: Is it a 404 or 500 error? Is it being served from a public folder or transpiled at server while sending?

Comment: provide your static middleware initialization code and path where your `Modulo.jsx` on server

Comment: If I try with `<script type="text/jsx" src="/Modulo.jsx" /></script>` I get a 404 error. My both files are in ./views of my server. I've also tried with `./views/Modulo.jsx`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't setup express to serve static files, you should have something like the following in your setup:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This will serve everything in the `public` directory as a static resource, which is what your `script` tag needs.

---

However, you don't normally import other jsx modules directly into the HTML and it should be imported into the main bundle using something like:

```
var Modulo = require('./Modulo.jsx');
```

but you will also need to put the following line at the bottom of your Modulo.jsx file:

```
module.exports = Modulo
```

There are other ways to import/require modules, but that's probably the way to go. Update your answer with your main module and more of your HTML and build process (including if you build it in the browser) if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

First: jsx is nothing the browser can understand. You need to transpile it to javascript using tools like babel with react preset, or webpack.

Second: Even if you include the same code transpiled to js in your html, it won't do anything. You need to mount it to a DOM element, with reactDOM. Something like:

```
ReactDOM.render('<Modulo/>', document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is apparently the good approach. But now that I setted up Webpack and Babel I'm not able anymore to run my server with express. I configured the entry point as my index.js file but I don't see anything on port 5000